# can't write unknown attribute `followings_count` with has_many though association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, associations, simple-form

I'm trying to use has_many though association with Rails 5. I'm getting this error when saving my "category".

> ActiveModel::MissingAttributeError in CategoriesController#create
>
> can't write unknown attribute `followings_count`

Following model:

```
class Following < ApplicationRecord  
  belongs_to :category, touch: true, counter_cache: true
  belongs_to :followed_category, counter_cache: :followers_count, class_name: 'Category'
end
```

Category model:

```
class Category < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :followings
    has_many :followed_categories, through: :followings
    
    has_many :followers, foreign_key: :followed_category_id, class_name: 'Following'
    has_many :follower_categories, through: :followers, source: :category
end
```

Category controller:

```
class CategoriesController < InheritedResources::Base
  private
    def category_params
      params.require(:category).permit(:name, :description, :display_in_navbar, post_ids: [], followed_category_ids: [])
    end
end
```

_form.html.rb

```
<%= simple_form_for(@category) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>
  <%= f.error_notification message: f.object.errors[:base].to_sentence if f.object.errors[:base].present? %>

  <div class="form-inputs">
    <%= f.input :name %>
    <%= f.association :followed_categories, as: :check_boxes %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-actions">
    <%= f.button :submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Oy. It might be your singular/pluralization etc? I love the natural language of Rails but sometimes you get a mess like this of "follower/following/followed". Are you able to access all of those relations in the console? i.e. If you have examples in your DB, can you get it to return `@some_category.followings_count` ?

Comment: Normally a `has_many_through` requires a join model. `has_and_belongs_to_many` does not. It looks like you are using some sort of self-referential design. Do you happen to have a table diagram for this? I'm thinking something along the lines of: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/images/association_basics/has_many_through.png

Comment: @Beartech I have a join model. its a "Following". I don't have a diagram as I used this guide: https://www.bhalash.com/archives/13544808202

Comment: And do your relationships work on the console as referenced above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like counter cache is looking for a column called `followings_count` on the categories table. While you are there, I am guessing you migh be missing `followers_count` as well. This helped me understand it a bit better https://redpanthers.co/counter-cache-how-to-get-started/

Comment: You are correct. Now it works. Although I didn't fix it, I just removed this functionality as I don't need it now. Thanks.